# Is $\inf\{\sup\{\varepsilon>0\;;\;B(x,\varepsilon)\subset\Omega\}\;;\;x\in K\}>0$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be a bounded open set and $K\subset\Omega$ a compact set.

For each $x\in K$, define $\varepsilon_x=\sup\{\varepsilon>0\;;\;B(x,\varepsilon)\subset\Omega\}$.

Is it possible to prove that $\inf\{\varepsilon_x\;;\;x\in K\}>0$? Or is there any counterexample?

Thanks.

Comment: If i am not mistaken, this should be doable. What $\inf\{\varepsilon_x \mid x \in K\}$ is geometrically, is the least distance between $\partial K$ and $\partial \varOmega$ I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. $\varepsilon_x$ is the distance of $x$  from the complement of $\Omega$,

$$\varepsilon_x = \inf \{ d(x,y) : y \in \mathbb{R}^n\setminus\Omega\} =: \operatorname{dist}(x,\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\Omega).$$

Now, $\operatorname{dist}(x,A)$ is a Lipschitz-continuous function for any $A$ (with Lipschitz-constant $1$), in particular continuous. On $\Omega$, it is positive, and since $K$ is compact, there is an $x_0 \in K$ with

$$\operatorname{dist}(x_0,\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\Omega) = \inf \{ \operatorname{dist}(x,\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\Omega) : x \in K\}.$$

Since $x_0 \in \Omega$ and $\Omega$ is open,

$$\operatorname{dist}(x_0,\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\Omega) > 0.$$